# inserting a function into a module's namespace using a decorator

Tags: python, namespaces, decorator

I've got a decorator, but I'd like to store the original function in the namespace for future reference, such that I end up with a decorated and non-decorated version of the function.
I'm inserting that original function into the namespace like that:

```
def crossover(cross):  
    def ecspy_crossover(random, candidates, args):  
    # ... decorator magic
    globals()['single_'+cross.func_name] = cross
```

However, when I import the module, the single_* functions do not show up.
When I launch pdb in this module, this function is present in the namespace...
[ there is no `__all__`statement in this module... ]

Any ideas?

Comment: There won't be any `single_*` functions in the namespace until you execute `crossover()` one or more times -- which is not something that will happen magically when you import the module. You can add some calls to it at the module level outside of any other functions or method definitions and they will be executed, then the `single_*` function names get created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add the original function as an attribute of the wrapped function? In fact that's exactly what `functools.wraps` does in Python 3.2, it stores the original function in the `__wrapped__` attribute.

Regarding your question, I would guess that your problem is that you are adding the function into the global namespace of the module containing the decorator rather than that of the decorated function. You can use `f.__globals__` to get at the correct global namespace.

Comment: I agree functools.wrap is really useful for deco's, but the f.__globals__ was what I was looking for. On the money, thanks Duncan!